# Why was Naruto's Room dirty when he came back from training with Jiraya?

Tags: naruto

Naruto returns to Konoha in Shippuden and finds his room dirty. But later in the series it is revealed that Konohamaru cleaned Naruto's Room. Is this some kind of mistake or is that two completely different timelines?

When room is dirty

> Naruto: Finally Home Sweet Home, The old place hasn't changed a bit. Oh, well bound to be a little dusty being closed up for a couple of years.
>
> <sub>NARUTO SHIPPUDEN (Episode 7: Run, Kankuro)</sub>

[image]

[image]

When room is clean and spotless

> Konohamaru: All Done, everything nice and clean now.
>
> Sakura: Wow, you really cleaned Naruto's room.
>
> Moegi: That's right , Naruto been away for 3 whole years and it really needed it.
>
> Konohamaru: His place is spotless. It is ready to welcome him home >and so are we.
>
> <sub>NARUTO SHIPPUDEN (Episode 422: The Ones Who Will Inherit)</sub>

[image]

Comment: It's been a long time since I watched Naruto. So, it would be better if you provide the episode number. // Also, if you were away for 2 years, you'll find your house dirty.

Comment: I wants to answer, but in which episode Konohamaru said that? @FumikageTokoyami he talks about episode 7 in shippuuden.

Comment: @USerNAme Thank you. I just reviewed the episode and indeed the room is dirty as expected but I don't remember Konohamaru cleaning his room.

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami that's why I wants him to say in which episode doe he hear that, or any answer would be half empty...

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami I edited the question, added the episode names along with part of transcript and images. Please take a look.

Comment: @USerNAme I edited the question, added the episode names along with part of transcript and images. Please take a look.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but episode 422 is considered a filler episode. Fillers are notorious for creating plot holes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple explanation to this is that it's a plot hole created by a filler episode:

> The episode shows Konohamaru cleaning Naruto's apartment so that it is clean when Naruto returns. This contradicts episode 7 of Naruto: Shippūden where Naruto returns to his apartment to find it dusty and filled with cobwebs
>
> <sub>[The Ones Who Will Inherit](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/The_Ones_Who_Will_Inherit)</sub>

A <strike>plausible</strike> explanation (albeit shaky at best) to fill in this plot hole is that this episode is an unspoken view<sup>1</sup> of Konohamaru's dream while under the effects of the [Infinite Tsukuyomi](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Infinite_Tsukuyomi). This episode occurs right before Infinite Tsukuyomi is casted, so the timeline is a little off.

The Infinite Tsukuyomi put the victims into a dream world that is filled with their deepest desires. This filler episode seems to focus around Konohamaru both learning the Rasengan and improving his Sexy Jutsu technique in a comedic way.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is not listed under the section of [known dreams](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Infinite_Tsukuyomi#Known_Dreams).

Comment: Good thing you strikethrough "plausible" because that is the answer. Once you get under the effects of IT, you will go under dreams where you can fulfil your desires and slowly realize that "this" is your reality (although you are very much trapped in a dream). I was unsure of the answer at first, because I don't remember which episode was it from (that's why I asked that above) {tbh, I skipped every IT episode, I assume it didn't hold any relevance to the core story}